# How do you run Jasmine tests in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm using [jasmine-npm](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm). `jasmine-init` sets it up such that you could run `jasmine` in the terminal to test your code.

I recall seeing these tests in the browser before and would like to see them there. How would I run the tests in the browser? (This seems like this should be something that's easy to research, but I swear that I've spent over 2 hours researching this and can't figure it out).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1:

> JASMINE STANDALONE
>
> Included is a sample app and sample tests. Open SpecRunner.html and run the included specs. Both the source files and their respective specs are linked in the  of the SpecRunner.html.
>
> To start using Jasmine, replace the source/spec files with your own.
>
> Load the SpecRunner.html in your favorite browser
>
> https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html

Option 2: https://github.com/airportyh/testem.